# сортировка односвязного списка 3

Tags: c++, сортировка, список

Реализован линейный односвязный список. Как его можно отсортировать вставками? Как реализовать функцию void Sort()? Например нужно в обратном порядке все поставить?

```
using namespace std;

struct element 
{
 int x; 
 element *Next; 
};

class List 
{
 element *Head; 
 public:
  List() {Head=NULL;} 
 ~List(); 
 void Add(int x); 
 void Show(); 
 void Sort();
};

List::~List() 
{
    while (Head!=NULL)  
     {    
        element *temp=Head->Next; 
        delete Head; 
        Head=temp; 
     }
}

void List::Add(int x) 
{
 element *temp=new element; 
temp->x=x; 
temp->Next=Head; 
Head=temp; 
}

void List::Show() 
{
 element *temp=Head; 

 while (temp!=NULL) 
 {
  cout<<temp->x<<" "; 
  temp=temp->Next; 
 }
}

int main()
{

  int N; 
  int x; 
  List lst; 

   cout<<"N = ";cin>>N; 

for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
  cout<<i+1<<". x = "; cin>>x; 
  lst.Add(x); 
 }

lst.Show(); 

}
```

Comment: как можно удвоить элементы списка?

Comment: Алгоритм сортировки вставками нормально описан даже на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_вставками). Искать место для вставки вам придется начиная с первого элемента, так как список односвязный и нет возможности перейти к предыдущему элементу. Что значит *удвоить элементы списка*?